# How to pass a parameter in a command without run the parameter content?

Tags: linux, shell-script, system-programming

Good days.

I have a little problem.
I have this function in bash script

```
function denyCheck(){
    file=$(readlink -f $(which $(printf "%s\n" "$1")))
    if [[ -x $file ]];then
           return false
    else
           return true
    fi
}
denyCheck "firefox"
```

This function I pass her a string, what is a comman, and this resolv the orginal path where is the command (by example: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh) and if the file is executable return true else false.

But the problem is...The parameter (in the example "firefox") run it as command and open the browser firefox.

How can I do for that the parameter not run it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should rather be:

```
cmd_canonical_path() {
  local cmd_path
  cmd_path=$(command -v -- "$1") &&
    cmd_path=$(readlink -e -- "$cmd_path") &&
    [ -x "$cmd_path" ] &&
    REPLY=$cmd_path
} 2> /dev/null
```

And then use for instance as:

```
if cmd_canonical_path firefox; then
  printf '%s\n' "firefox found in $REPLY executable"
else
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "no executable file found for firefox"
fi
```

In shells, all commands have an exit status that indicates either success (0) or failure (any other number whose values can help discriminate between different types of failure).

For instance, the `[` command, when passed `-x`, `/path/to/some/file` and `]` as arguments will return true if the process that executes it has execute permission for the `/path/to/some/file` file (or directory).

A function can also have an exit status, and that's the exit status of the last command it ran before it returned (or the number passed to `return` if called there).

The success or failure status of commands is checked by shell constructs such as `if`/`until`/`while` statements or its boolean operators `||`  and `&&`. *Commands* are the shells' booleans if you like.

`cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` returns success / true is all of `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3` succeed. And `cmd2` is not even executed if `cmd1` fails, same for `cmd3`.

So above `cmd_canonical_path` succeeds if `command -v -- "$1"` (the standard builtin¹ command to lookup a command and output its path²; while `which` was some similar command but intended for csh users only) **and** then that `readlink -e` (which works like `readlink -f` to canonicalise³ a path but will return failure if it can't while `readlink -f` will do a best effort) succeeds **and** then that the current process has execute permission for that file, **and** then (and only then) that that path is successfully assigned to the `REPLY`<sup>4</sup> variable (plain assignments are always successful).

If not, the function will return failure: the exit status of the first command that failed in that `cmd && cmd && cmd` chain.

You'll also notice that `$REPLY` is left alone and not modified if the canonical path to the command cannot be determined or it's not executable by you.

Some other problems with your approach:

- That `$(printf '%s\n' "$1")` doesn't make much sense. In sh/bash, it's the same as `$1` (at least with the default value of `$IFS`) and is equally wrong as it's not quoted. If you want to pass the contents of the first positional parameter to a command, the syntax is `cmd "$1"`.
- When you want some arbitrary data you pass to a command to be treated as a non-option arguments, you need to pass it after the `--` argument that marks the end of options: `which -- "$1"`, `readlink -f -- "$(...)"`.
- `return` takes a (optional) number as argument (the exit code for the function), not `true`/`false` (you also seem to have them reversed as you said the function was to return true if the file was executable). If not passed a number, the function's exit status will be that of the last command run in the function. So `if cmd; then return 0; else return 1; fi` is better written as just `cmd; return`. Though here you don't even need the `return` since `cmd` (`[[ -x $file ]]` in your case) is the last command in your function.
- You're blindly passing the output of `which` (incorrectly as you forgot the `--` and to  quote the `$(...)`) to `readlink` without having first checked that it succeeded.

As a final note, had you used `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could have done:

```
firefox_path==firefox
firefox_canonical_path=$firefox_path:P
```

To get the path of the `firefox` command. `=firefox` expands to the path of the `firefox` command and aborts the shell with an error if it can't be found. You can intercept that error in an *`always` block* if need be. The `:P` modifier does a `realpath()` equivalent on the parameter it's applied to, similar to what GNU `readlink -f` does. No need to check for execute permissions as `zsh`'s `=cmd` operator would only expand to a path that is executable.

---

<sup>¹ and as it's a builtin of the shell, you'll find its documentation in the shell's manual. For `bash`, see `info bash command` for instance.</sup>

<sup>² with the caveat that `command -v cmd` outputs `cmd` is `cmd` is a function or shell builtin which could be a problem here.</sup>

<sup>³ a canonical absolute path starts with `/`, has no symlink component (they've all be resolved to their target), no `.` / `..` component, no sequences of two or more `/`s.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> `$REPLY` is commonly used (though that's only a convention) as the default variable for a function or shell builtin to return a value in. Alternatively, your function could *output* the result, and the caller would run `firefox_path=$(cmd_canonical_path firefox)`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function denyCheck(){
```

is a mix of the standard function declaration `func()`, and ksh's `function func`. Bash supports the combination, other shells might not, but there's no reason to do it. Just write `denyCheck()` instead.

Here,

```
file=$(readlink -f $(which $(printf "%s\n" "$1")))
```

that `$(printf ...)` is unnecessary, and since it's unquoted, actually
counterproductive. The result of that command substitution would be subject to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), while the quoted `"$1"` isn't, and you could just use that instead instead.

`which` is considered to have some issues, and the standard POSIX alternative is `command -v`, see [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/170373)

The big difference between the two is that `command` is a shell builtin, and knows about e.g. aliases (if you run it from an interactive shell), which `which` doesn't (except in csh but you're not using that). This may or may not be a good thing: e.g. `command -v ls` might return `alias ls='ls -vF --color=auto'`, which isn't a path you can use.

In any case, you should to quote the command substitution to avoid issues with word splitting and add `--` to mark the end of options. This is to guard against the rare path that contains whitespace or starts with a `-`. So that would be:

```
file=$(readlink -f -- "$(command -v -- "$1")")  # or
file=$(readlink -f -- "$(which -- "$1")")
```

Then,

```
return false
```

is just an error: the `return` command takes a number. But you could just run the command called `false` to get a falsy return status. So either use
`return 1` or just `false`. (Since you're just inverting the result of the test, you could also use just `! [[ -x "$file" ]]` instead of the whole `if` statement, writing it out might be clearer to the next reader.)

So:

```
denycheck() {
    file=$(readlink -f -- "$(command -v -- "$1")")
    if [[ -x "$file" ]]; then
        return 1  # command found and executable, falsy result
    else
        return 0  # not executable, truthy result
    fi
}
```